# Render and Screenshot a web page

Tags: android, html, image

I am looking for a `Java library` where I can render a webpage and then save this rendered page as an image. I recently was able to find out how to do this in python with PyQT4. But haven't found a good solution in Java that should work properly on Android.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) project a while ago and found it pretty interesting (it also saves to Images).

Even though it's a command line tool, you can easily call it from your Java code.

Comment: Ill look into this thanks, i plan on using this on an android app so im not sure if it will work.

Comment: Oh, so I think it won't be possible. I've added an Android tag to your question for better results.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried [Html2Image](https://code.google.com/p/java-html2image/)?

Comment: Yea, it isnt able to render much besides pretty basic html